# Cloud9 и mLab не устанавливается коннект

Tags: node.js, mongodb, хостинг

Всем привет. Разместил свой node.js сайт на Cloud9. Когда разрабатывал на локале то использовал облачное хранилище для MongoDB - mLab. Хотелось бы продолжить его использовать но на сервере cloud9 при подлючении у базе на mLab возникает ошибка.

```
Failed to load https://c9users.io/_user_content/authorize?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Freact-proj-simon1400.c9users.io%2Fadmin%2Freviews: Redirect from 'https://c9users.io/_user_content/authorize?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Freact-proj-simon1400.c9users.io%2Fadmin%2Freviews' to 'https://c9.io/api/nc/auth?response_type=token&client_id=user.content&state=https%3A%2F%2Freact-proj-simon1400.c9users.io%2Fadmin%2Freviews' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://react-proj-simon1400.c9users.io' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Как исправить эту проблему.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение!

В cloud9 свой workspace на начале я сделал полностью приватным. И это не давало ему принимать внешние запросы. Чтобы это исправить надо в приватном workspace в IDE справа вверху кликнуть на кнопку Share и зачеркнуть чекбокс Public возле Application.